# Issue with TODAY in Power BI Desktop and Web

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

TODAY() in power Bi desktop is giving me my local timezone but TODAY() in PowerBI app is giving me different date and time.

Does any one know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI online makes use of a different time zone GMT. That's why your date is different in dekstop, where you use your local timezone as configured in the settings.